# Should we make a model for specific views or a model can be used by many views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

Is a model meant for a specific view only? 
Or multiple views can reuse the same model?

For instance, a typical website has registration and login feature. 
Is it necessary to do two different models (RegistrationViewModel & LoginViewModel) for this registration and login views respectively?

Or I can have a model, let's say named as UserAccountViewModel

```
public class UserAccountViewModel
{
  public string email {get; set;}
  public string password {get; set;}
  public string confirmPassword {get; set;}
}
```

And both registration and login views can use the use the same model (UserAccountViewModel)?

If two ways are do-able, then which is a better practice?

Comment: The basic idea of the MVC model is that you separate views from models, through one or more controls. So I think it is a bad idea to tie a model to a view.

Comment: So u mean using UserAccountViewModel is preferable?

Comment: Yes, this model could be used by both the views.

Comment: It would not be suitable in the example you gave - a Login model for example would not have a `ConfirmPassword` property (which would also have a `[Compare]` validation attribute, so posting back to a Login post method would always result in `ModelState` being invalid)

Comment: The better practice is using reusable viewmodels that can bind to multiple views. However there are certain cases which one model should bind to one viewmodel, e.g. models with comparison between properties which affects `ModelState.IsValid` property.